# <ul> Background colour won't work. I'm trying to add a background for my page breadcrumbs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add my website breadcrumbs to a list and change the list background to #0765de, i have tried as seen below, only the `<li>` background will change colour.

I have to change the width of li so the text is in the page so the background cuts off. that's why I need it in ul.

Heres the HTML:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb_unli">
<li class="breadcrumb_unli">{ include'breadcrumb' }</li>
</ul>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
.breadcrumb_unli ul {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #0765de;
}


.breadcrumb_unli li {
width: 60%;
color: white;
margin: auto;
margin-top: -30px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does your breadcrumb have an `<a>` tag nested inside the `<li>`? If so, try `ul li a { color: white; }`

Comment: it should be `ul.breadcrumb_unli` not `.breadcrumb_unli ul` for your css selector. "breadcrumb_unli" is your ul

Answer (score 0):

to select a ul with a specific class you should do this:

```
ul.breadcrumb_unli {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #0765de;
}
```

if it didn't work, try adding `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to the ul

Comment: Hi, I'm using liquid (Shopify) this is how you select in this I believe